# How do I export methods from C++ to python?

Tags: python, c++

I am using Python 3.3.5.   I have a pyd file I created in Visual Studio 2015 which is really a C++ dll from what I understand.   How do I export my C++ methods to Python? Can someone please provide a sample or at least point me to the right documentation that describes how to do this?

Comment: You need to `import `it into a Python script in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In given scenario this should be easy, just take a look at [this faq question](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll) for requirements. If they are met (they should be) then you can just import that module.

If this is not exactly what you are looking for you can look around boost.python library in [boost.python documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html). There are some easy tutorials there that you can look through to see if this is what you need.